# How to test DOM methods in embed js script library?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, dom, embedded-resource

I am working in a Javascript library to embed in the browser.

The thing is that I was started the project from https://github.com/krasimir/webpack-library-starter and I would to test my library but I have a problem with the `DOM` because my proyect hasn't got html so, I don't know how I should to test the `DOM` methods.

The library is to embed in to our clients websites, the idea is to make a embed script like google maps, analytics sdk, etc.

I am using `chai` and `mocha` to test but maybe I should to change to `ava` or something like.

I know that in React for example you have tools to simulate the `DOM` but it is in vanilla JS so... help please.

**Example of my library class:**

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor(htmlElement) {
   this.clientWebsiteHTMLElement = htmlElement;
   this.addChild();
  }

  addChild() {
   let child = document.createElement('div');
   this.clientWebsiteHTMLElement.appendChild(child);
  }
}
```

**Example of my-lib.js**

```
import { MyClass } from './my-class.js'


if (window && document) {
  (function (window, document){
    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    let myClass = new MyClass(container);

    window.myLib = myClass;
  })(window, document) 
}
```

**Example of entry point (In to the client website, is not in the same project):**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <div id="container"></div>

  <script src="http://myserver.com/to/serve/embed/scripts/myLib-bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Really is more complex than this, but the solution are the same.

How I can test that for example?

Thanks! :D

Comment: The most commonly used tool for this is JSDOM: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: Oh great, can you write a more specific example to test this?(Using with chai or whatever testing suite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Mocha tests are executed with Node.js, meaning by default, there is no browser available that can provide a DOM that provides APIs like [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document) or [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/window).

A popular tool to provide a DOM for these tests is [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).

Here's a simple example how you could test your class `MyClass`:

```
import { MyClass } from '../modules/MyClass';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const dom = new JSDOM(
  '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>'
);

global.document = dom.window.document;

describe('My class', () => {
  it('adds an element to the HTML element passed to its constructur', () => {
    const htmlElement = document.getElementById('root');
    const myClass = new MyClass(htmlElement);
    expect(htmlElement.children.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

**Note:** Since you're already considering switching your testing library, may I suggest switching to [Jest](https://jestjs.io)? It comes with JSDom pre-installed.